# c# How to access elements of a list of objects consisting of int and string in foreach

Tags: c#, list, class, foreach

I have a list of objects of a class, made of a string and an int.

```
public class PatternInfo 
{
    private string prpatternname;
    private int prpatterntier;

    public PatternInfo(string patternname, int patterntier)
    {        
        prpatternname = patternname;
        prpatterntier = patterntier;
    }
}
```

This is in a seperate file.

I have a list of such objects: 
`public List<PatternInfo> patternlist;`

Now for each obejct of this class in a list, I want to set values of variables to those two values:

```
foreach (PatternInfo x in patternlist)
{
    string a = patternname;
    int b = patterntier;
}
```

for some reason I get "the name patternname/patterntier does not exist in current context". I have tried playing with some solutions, but can't get it to work, please help :)

Comment: "patternname" is not the same as "prpatternname" and the latter is private

Comment: Changing to public doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To align with OP:

```
    public class PatternInfo
    {
        public string prpatternname { get; }
        public int prpatterntier { get; }

        public PatternInfo(string patternname, int patterntier)
        {

            prpatternname = patternname;
            prpatterntier = patterntier;

        }
    }
```

As you haven't provided how you declare patternlist, I made up the following:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<PatternInfo> patternlist = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            patternlist.Add(new PatternInfo(i.ToString(), i));
        foreach(PatternInfo x in patternlist)
        {
            string a = x.prpatternname;
            int b = x.prpatterntier;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't set it as public and didn't call it properly.

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer you preferred btw :)

Comment: I must admit that the other answer seems logial as I understand my mistake now, but your answer was the one that made me understand it :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

This is because the attributes are private and attributes of `x`. Add this to a `PatternInfo`:

```
public string name { get;}
public int tier {get;}
```

Then, in the loop, you can have the following:

```
string a = x.name;
int b = x.tier;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't set it as public and didn't call it properly.